# Variable instead of node name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I can use JavaScript variable instead of node name in the render to use in jsx? Something like this:

```
var First = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var nodeName = this.props.node; // this.props.node = 'Second';
    return <{nodeName}/>;
  }
});
var Second = React.creactClass({/*...*/});
```

Comment: It's likely not possible with JSX, but you aren't forced to use JSX to write in React.

Comment: Have you tried `return < dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: nodeName}} />;`

Comment: Although, this smells a lot like a design smell to me. There's a good reason there isn't an easy way to do this.

Comment: I agree without JSX) Have this `React.createElement(eval(nodeName));` But I dont want use "eval"

Comment: I don't understand what this is trying to achieve. Why not just use a `<div>{this.props.children}</div>` construct and pass in the element you want as a child? This stinks of an XY Problem to me.

Comment: because I have a lot of elements of the `Second` type, and I do not know which will come `this.props.node` to the `First`

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use JSX in this case.

```
var First = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var nodeName = this.props.node; // this.props.node = 'Second';
    return React.createElement(nodeName);
  }
});
var Second = React.createClass({/*...*/});
```

This is ultimately what JSX results in, when compiled into Vanilla JS.

Comment: `React.createElement` return node that I need, but this node does not call `Second`

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? The above code does what you tried to do in the OP. By the way, if you need to pass props, you can do that as the second argument, and children either as an array in the third argument or just `3..nth` argument: `React.createElement(node, props, children)`.

Comment: its work only with "eval" - `return React.createElement(eval(nodeName));`

Comment: Can you try `console.log(nodeName)` right before the return statement. `eval` should never be necessary.